# hiding/showing a table row breaks layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, show-hide

I'm trying to hide and show table rows, the following works but breaks the layout , ie the empty `<td>` s lose their width is there a way to prevent this?

```js
$(document).on("click ", "tr.grey", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $( "tr.sales-details" ).removeClass( "show" );
  $(this).nextUntil(".grey").addClass( "show" );
});
```

```css
tbody tr.sales-details, tbody tr.sales-details-title{
  display: none;
  &.show{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Surgeon name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Antiquity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grey">
      <td>Alex Lloyd</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
      <td>new client</td>
      <td>2690.58 USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details-title">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><strong>Seller:</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Percentage:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sales-details">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Support</td>
      <td>2690.58 USD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `{visibility:hidden}` and `{visibility:visible}` to hide or display the elements - this will haide content but keep its place in the DOM and not cause reflowing / reformatting that disply:none causes.

```
tbody tr.sales-details, tbody tr.sales-details-title{
  visibility: hidden;
  &.show{
    visibility:visible;
  }
}
```